# ¿Como validar un elemento que SI exista en selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

El programa funciona bien.
Pero necesito añadir una condicion para cuando el elemento no exista y asi evitar que se crashee
Despues de pegar el nombre de usuario en el recuadro de busqueda de whatsaap debe aprecer el recuadro con el contacto
En caso de que SI exista hacele click
En caso que NO exista borrar el nombre del buscador y pegar el siguiente nombre que esta en la lista CONTACTOS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pyperclip
import click

chromedriver = './chromedriver'
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
browser.maximize_window()

time.sleep(20)
print("espacio de lectura de qr")

with open ('contactos.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    contactos=[contacto.strip() for contacto in f.readlines()]
    print(contactos)

with open('mensaje.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    mensaje=f.read()
for contacto in contactos:
    search_xpath='//div[@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="3"]'
    search_box=WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, search_xpath))
    )
    search_box.clear()

    pyperclip.copy(contacto)
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')
    time.sleep(2)
    print("nombre de contacto pegado en buscador")
########Esta es la condicion que necesito validar#######
    contacto_titulo=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@dir="auto"]')#validate
#Si es correcta hacer click, si no aparece el recuadro, borrar el nombre de la barra de busqueda y pegar el siguiente##
contacto_titulo.click()
time.sleep(1)
print("contacto seleccionado")
#not vadate, if it doesn't exist, delete the contact name and paste a new one, follow the 
cycle
search_box.send_keys(Keys.DELETE) #pass a next contacto
```

Comment: Hola  Zen Aku, bienvenido, estas en SOes, el idioma soportado es el español, te sugiero que traduzcas tu pregunta o la traslades a SO, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Para preguntas en inglés, ve a [so].

Comment: Para que el programa no crashee deberías capturar la excepción.